# Build spatio-temporal numpy array (3D) from spatial data array (2D) and a temporal data array (2D)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, spatial

I have a first 2D array that represents locations of spatial points. Let's name it A. My first array has a shape of (N, 2) where N represents the number of spatial points and 2 corresponds to both variables x and y. Then, I have a second 2D array corresponding to a time series B of shape (T, 3) where T is the number of timesteps and 3 corresponds to time t and two other variables that I will name y1, y2. What I want is to build a 3D array C of shape (N, T, 2 + 3) that associates for each spatial point the second array B so that C have the following columns: (x, y, t, y1, y2) or (t, y1, y2, x, y). I can do it by loop but with large data, it becomes uneffiient. Do you have a more efficient way to do it? Below, an example:

```
A = np.array([
    [1, 2],
    [3, 4]
])

B = np.array([
    [-1, -1],
    [-2, -2],
    [-3, -3]
])

C = np.zeros((2, 3, 4))
for j in range(2):
    C[j, :, :2] = np.tile(A[j:j + 1, :], (3, 1))
    C[j, :, 2:] = B

print(A)
print(B)
print(C)
```

Outputs:

```
A
 [[1 2]
 [3 4]]

B
 [[-1 -1]
 [-2 -2]
 [-3 -3]]

C
 [[[ 1.  2. -1. -1.]
   [ 1.  2. -2. -2.]
   [ 1.  2. -3. -3.]]

  [[ 3.  4. -1. -1.]
   [ 3.  4. -2. -2.]
   [ 3.  4. -3. -3.]]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NumPy broadcasting!

First, you need to reshape A and B in such a way that they can be broadcasted together. You can achieve this by adding new axes to both A and B:

```py
A = np.array([
    [1, 2],
    [3, 4]
])

B = np.array([
    [-1, -1],
    [-2, -2],
    [-3, -3]
])

A_reshaped = A[:, np.newaxis, :]  # shape (N, 1, 2)
B_reshaped = B[np.newaxis, :, :]  # shape (1, T, 3)
```

Now, you can use NumPy broadcasting to combine the reshaped A and B arrays then concatenate the broadcasted arrays along the last axis.

```py
A_broadcasted, B_broadcasted = np.broadcast_arrays(A_reshaped, B_reshaped)
C = np.concatenate((A_broadcasted, B_broadcasted), axis=2) # shape (N, T, 2 + 3)
```

The output will be the expected result:

```
[[[ 1  2 -1 -1]
  [ 1  2 -2 -2]
  [ 1  2 -3 -3]]

 [[ 3  4 -1 -1]
  [ 3  4 -2 -2]
  [ 3  4 -3 -3]]]
```

Comment: Wow, that work very well ! Thanks. Please, just modify these lines A_broadcasted, B_broadcasted = np.broadcast_arrays(A_reshaped, B_reshaped)
C = np.concatenate((A_reshaped, B_reshaped), axis=2)  # shape (N, T, 2 + 3) to A_broadcasted, B_broadcasted = np.broadcast_arrays(A_reshaped, B_reshaped)
C = np.concatenate((A_broadcasted, B_broadcasted), axis=2)  # shape (N, T, 2 + 3)

Comment: Oh yup sorry. This was from a previous test and I forgot to update the concatenation once it worked. Good catch!